# Java for loops while keeping variable within a range

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested, iteration

Im trying to run a two for loops that iterate over something like colored large square (for example 300x300) and replacing it with the colors(or pixels) of a smaller square (say 100x100) which is what k and l represent.

Essentially, I was wondering how to keep k and l running between 0-100 and restarting once it hits 100, but also keep i and j running the whole time. I tried used 4 nested for loops but it did not work properly, although I'm starting to think that may be a solution, but that would be very inefficient.

Please let me know if this sounds a little confusing I will try my best to explain more clearly, thanks.

excuse the psuedocode

```
for (i=0; i < width; i++)
        for (j=0; i< height; j++)
           set(i, j , pixel(k,l));
```

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here; are you tiling an image onto a larger image, or resizing by nearest-neighbour sampling?

Comment: @kaya3 tiling an image over a larger image, so basically each smaller image in this example would be 100x100 so it would be 3 images across and 3 down for a 300x300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be to tile an image onto another image. You have `width` and `height` for the target image's dimensions, so let's say `sourceWidth` and `sourceHeight` are the source image's dimensions (100 by 100, in your example).

To tile an image, you want `k == i % sourceWidth` and `l == j % sourceHeight`, so that the pixel you read from the source image "wraps around" the boundaries. These should be [invariant conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant). The simplest way to satisfy them is to declare them that way directly:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
    int k = i % sourceWidth;
    for(int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
        int l = j % sourceHeight;
        set(i, j, pixel(k, l));
    }
}
```

This does a lot of `%` operations, which could be quite inefficient, but it gives us a correct piece of code to transform. If we are incrementing `k` and `l`, then there are two properties needed to maintain the invariants:

1. `k` and `i` are incremented in unison; and `l` and `j` are incremented in unison.
2. When `k` reaches `sourceWidth` it must wrap back to 0, likewise for `l` and `sourceHeight`.

```java
for(int i = 0, k = 0; i < width; ++i, ++k) {
    if(k == sourceWidth) { k = 0; }
    for(int j = 0, l = 0; j < height; ++j, ++l) {
        if(l == sourceHeight) { l = 0; }
        set(i, j, pixel(k, l));
    }
}
```

Note that the `for` loop initialiser and stepper now declare and update two variables, for both loops. This is allowed in Java.

This is likely to be faster than doing a lot of `%` operations, but note that branching with `if` statements [can also slow down an algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor), so you may want to benchmark it to be sure.

In the special case where source image's dimensions are powers of two, we can achieve the same result with a fast bitwise operation: `i % sourceWidth` will be equivalent to `i & (sourceWidth - 1)`:

```java
// special case: sourceWidth and sourceHeight are powers of 2
int wMask = sourceWidth - 1, hMask = sourceHeight - 1;
for(int i = 0, k = 0; i < width; ++i, ++k) {
    for(int j = 0, l = 0; j < height; ++j, ++l) {
        set(i, j, pixel(i & wMask, j & hMask));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to implement something like the second code you wrote but it didn't work properly, but I was able to figure it out after reading your response, very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
      if(k > 100) {
        k = 0;
      }

      if(l > 100) {
        l = 0;
      }

      k++;
      l++;

      set(i, j , pixel(k,l));
    }
}
```

Comment: I failed to mention that 'l' has to cycle through to 100 while k= 0 and same for k=1, similar to a nested for-loop, again which is what I tried but couldn't get to work properly.